# How to use metapost(.mp) file in .tex file in overleaf

Tags: graphics, pdftex, overleaf, includegraphics, metapost

This question might be very silly but I am new in latex and I can’t find a possible solution to my problem.
I am making a latex document in overleaf and I have to use diagrams so I am trying to include .MP file in the latex file using graphicx package and the document is compiled with pdflatex this is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{figure.mp}
\end{document}
```

When I run it this error is coming:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .mp.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4     \includegraphics{figure.mp}
                                   
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

And I Am unable to find a way to convert my .mp file to .mps in overleaf as there is no shell, at least I am unable to find a shell.
Also please give  the correct method to convert the .mp file to .mps

Comment: This is my first time here in tex-stack exchange so feel free to point out any errors on my part

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! LaTeX graphics normally allows `jpg`, `png`, `pdf` and `eps` file but do not support `mp`. So the simple way is to use software or online websites to convert it to one of the supported image types.

Comment: Mp files are source code, they cannot be included directly. Needs to be compiled first. Not sure if overleaf can do that

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry can you give a site link which can convert the file

Comment: If you could switch to lualatex (which OL supports) you could use `luamplib`.

Comment: I previously found a site that looked so convincing but yielded errors on a simple test. So `mpost` can be used to convert it to an eps file and you upload the eps file. (Renaming from `.1` to `.eps` is required) However, this needs LaTeX installed on your PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's doable. The code/packages needed depends on whether you're using pdflatex or lualatex as your [Overleaf project's compiler](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler).

Assuming we're working with `arrows.mp` with the following contents:

```
beginfig(1);

z1=(0,0);
z2=(10mm,10mm);

drawarrow(z1--z2);
label.ulft(btex $A$ etex, .5[z1,z2]);

endfig;

bye
```

---

## pdflatex

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
MetaPost drawing coming up

\includegraphics{arrows.1}

\end{document}
```

[image: metapost + pdflatex]

---

## lualatex

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibverbatim{enable}
\begin{document}

MetaPost drawing coming up

\begin{mplibcode}
\input arrows.mp
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

And as @Thruston has pointed out, you can actually just paste your MetaPost code within `\begin{mplibcode}...\end{mplibcode}` when using `luamplib`. There is no need to create separate `.mp` files and using `\input`.

[image]

Comment: In the lualatex alternative, you could just put the MP drawing code in line.  There's no need to maintain separate source code for each drawing.

Comment: Sorry @Thruston for this atrocity; the user said they want to work with `.mp` files so I shoehorned the `\input` in...

Comment: No need to apologize!  Using `input` is a valid technique even with `luamplib`, I was just pointing out an alternative.   

By the way the MP command is `input` not `\input` -- but MP is being kind to you because it ignores all `\ ` characters (except in a `<string>`.  See p.179 of the Metafont book if interested).

Comment: I am compiling a project with .mp files in the `fig/` subdirectory, and have been trying to modify this `pdflatex` example to adapt. I could not make it work, though. Do you maybe have a working example for modifying the line `\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}`?